# iCloud Files refusing to upload

Tags: icloud, data-transfer

So I’ve got <del>40 gigabytes</del> **a bunch** of stuff on my disk that I’ve been trying to upload to iCloud so I don’t have to worry about it. Most of it is footage from my libraries in Final Cut Pro. Because it was hogging so much space, I changed some preferences in FCPX so that libraries were saved on iCloud. Immediately iCloud responded and started uploading. Then, it mysteriously got stuck. Nothing has uploaded now for around twelve hours, and the progress readout is frozen at this:

[image]

All of the folders and files in question have also acquired “waiting to upload” tags. Altering or moving the files results in them briefly appearing to start uploading again, only to revert right back to the way they were before.

[image]

Any and all help is appreciated. I’m running High Sierra on a 2014 MacBook Air, and my Internet speed should be able to handle the upload just fine. How can I get these files to upload to the cloud and offload them from my hard drive?

Comment: I am guessing you have tried a simple restart?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: Did something change? Let me know if my answer isn’t working for you...

Answer (score 4):

Thankfully, there’s an app to figure out exactly which files are uploading, which are set and which are failing / out of date with iCLoud.

Even better, it’s well described and actively being developed and I believe, free to use.

- https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2018/06/cirrus11.zip

The general release blog post is:

- https://eclecticlight.co/2018/05/19/cirrus-version-1-0-release-the-icloud-tool-is-ready-for-general-use/

Keep in mind that there are throttles to pause uploads after so many GB a day so your initial ingest might take a while if you just dumped a ton of data and are not leaving your Mac on and not sleeping overnight or over a period of several days. I would consider reducing the initial upload to 3 GB or so and let that catch up if you can at this point.

Comment: Please explain how Cirrus helped you solve this issue?

Comment: Hi @aseem - I'll edit the part about "what's up" It lists file by file what's happening and shows details you simply can't see from Finder or any control panel.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to download a random zip file and execute the program within locally.

Comment: @AnthonyKong Yes! So be sure gatekeeper is set, you trust the source and validate its notarized and/or signed or you can checksum the download. Checksum isn’t perfect since you can’t be sure if the validity of the sum, but until everyone is onboard code signing, it’s a good first step.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina 10.15.2